Is it good practice to create entity object as bean in configuration class?
My Spring Boot application uses Spring Data JDBC and has some setting values stored in database instead of Application.yml file.
Is it good practice to create entity object as bean in configuration class to load and store these setting values or is there a better approach?
Are there any pitfalls or potential issues with this method? Any advice would be greatly appreciated!
My sample code
@Configuration
public class SettingConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private final SettingTableRepository settingTableRepository;

    @Bean
    public List<SettingTable> settingTable() {
        return settingTableRepository.findAll();
    }
}


This @Bean will be created only once at the application start time and in case you will have a new value for the configuration you will have to restart the app. Why don't just invoke  the settingTableRepository.findAll(); method where you really need it ? But I suggest to export that configs to a property file for future in case you will have to scale the app or even to have it customizable for different environments.

@Scope("prototype") may be used along with @Bean in order to get fresh data. BR

I don't see any direct problems arising from this approach.
But it does look and feel wrong and I would recommend exposing the repository instead, potentially wrapped in a cache.
That would give a more flexible and better fitting access to this data.

Could you give me some sample code?
